# Error occurred in a Python script

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have implement cgi python script with apache web server.
I have below function:

```
def check(form=None, key=''):
    if form == None:
        return -1
    value = form.has_key(key)
    if value == False:
        return -1
    return 0
```

And this is my header:

"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"

But when I run it and pass nothing to form, below error was showed.

> A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of
>   function calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

And this line `value = form.has_key(key)` was marked as a error.

This is traceback, i see that fieldStorage does not create a dictionary to store key:

> ```
> /usr/lib/python2.7/cgi.py in has_key(self=FieldStorage(None, None, 'keyA=valA&keyB=valB&keyC=calC\x00\x00'), key='keyA')
> 587         """Dictionary style has_key() method."""
> 588         if self.list is None:
> =>589             raise TypeError, "not indexable"
> 590         return any(item.name == key for item in self.list)
> 591  builtin TypeError = <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
> ```
>
> : not indexable
>         args = ('not indexable',)
>         message = 'not indexable'

How do I fix this issues.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please paste the stacktrace

Comment: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ConfirmPassword.fcgi in check_input_param(form=FieldStorage(None, None, 'CMD=ConfirmPasswordRequest&password=1234&poweroff=0\x00\x00'), cmd_key='CMD')
     25     if form == None:
     26         return -1
=>   27     cmd_value = form.has_key(cmd_key)
     28     if cmd_value == False:
     29         return -1
cmd_value undefined, form = FieldStorage(None, None, 'CMD=ConfirmPasswordRequest&password=1234&poweroff=0\x00\x00'), form.has_key = <bound method FieldStorage.has_key of FieldStora...sswordRequest&password=1234&poweroff=0\x00\x00')>, cmd_key = 'CMD'

Comment: You said it yourself, you pass __nothing__ to `form`. If `form` is empty, you can't access `form.has_key(key)` because it's an invalid/empty object. Hence, the error.

Comment: To improve readability you're able to edit your question ;-)

Comment: Now I pass A=a&B=b&C=c in to form. But the same error occurred. I also can't get length of form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are executing the `check()` method but I have tested this by own and its working just fine for me.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
def check(form=None, key=''):
    if form == None:
        return -1
    value = form.has_key(key)
    if value == False:
       return -1
    return 0

def index():
    return check()
```

Output: `-1`

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(form=None, key=''):
    if form == None:
        return -1
    value = form.has_key(key)
    if value == False:
        return -1
    return 0

if "__main__" == __name__:
    check()
```

code as above will not raise error

Comment: OP is not executing the file using CLI. They want to execute it using web interface(apache+cgi).In this case your code will never get executed as this `if "__main__" == __name__:`  will always return false